# How to add markers and thumb labels to Angular Dart material-slider?

Tags: angular-dart

In AngularJS, I can create a material slider with a thumb label by using

```
<mat-slider thumbLabel tickInterval="1"></mat-slider>
```

but I can't find a way to implement something similar in Angular Dart.

I've looked at the documentation for Dart's `material-slider`, but there doesn't seem to be anything about a thumb label or markers.

When I try

```
<material-slider thumbLabel tickInterval="1"></material-slider>
```

in Angular Dart, no thumb label appears.

I'm aiming to create something similar to [React's slider with marks](http://react-component.github.io/slider/examples/marks.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have this yet, but watch the space. Someone is working on them so we should have the ability soon.